# What is space charge and how to calculate it?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, terminology, classical-electrodynamics

I want to clarify the meaning of [space charge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_charge).  What I know is that the space charge is the total charge in a small region in space. I really confuse this in the ion beam context. Many text book says for a low ion beam current the space charge is negligible. I have following questions to be cleared:

1) If I have an ion beam in vacuum, whatever if it is high or low current, I have a space charge right? If I take a small region on the path of the ion beam, the net charge in that region is not zero, despite the rate at which the ions entering and leaving that region. I am totally confused here in this context what in text books says that for a low current beam the space charge is negligible! Can any one explain me what is space charge here and what is the limit of the ion beam current which decide if the space charge is considerable or negligible?

2) What is the space charge between two ions held motionless in a vacuum?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not heard the term "space charge" before and I work with plasmas in space.  Do you mean net charge?  Charge density?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of ion beams, space charge is the tendency of the beam to expand transversely (perpendicular to the direction of the beam's travel) due to the mutual repulsion of the ions in the beam. All the ions have the same sign charge, so they repel. The name "space charge" comes from plasma physics where is is often computationally easier to treat the charges in motion as a continuous fluid rather than a set of point charges. Instead of calculated the mutual force between every particle (requiring $N^2$ calculations for $N$ particles), it's easier to treat the beam as a continuous blob of charge.

1. It is more helpful to think of the problem in a frame of reference that follows the beam. If you increase the current, you increase the density of charges in the beam, so there is a greater repulsive effect on every ion in the beam. Low current beams have fewer charges in them, so each ion feels less repulsive force, so the space charge effect is lessened.
2. Space charge isn't a number to calculate, but an effect that needs accounting for when simulating ion beams. Two ions of the same charge will repel each other, but this is an easy calculation. Space charge enters the picture when the number of particles is in the millions or billions.

Here's a paper from CERN about space charge: https://acceleratorinstitute.web.cern.ch/acceleratorinstitute/ACINST89/Schindl_Space_Charge.pdf

Here's a presentation from the US Particle Accelerator School on introductory space charge topics: https://uspas.fnal.gov/materials/10MIT/Preliminaries_of_Beam_Dynamics.pdf

I found these and others by Googling "particle beam space charge".